# Hook JS into WooCommerce Email function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add some JS for Trustpilot in my WooCommerce processing order emails (customer-processing-order.php). I am currently trying to just echo it with a function in functions.php like so:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_email_header', 'add_trustpilot_script', 9999, 3);

function add_trustpilot_script ($headers, $email_id, $order ){
$theSku = '';
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
          $sku = $item->get_sku();
          $theSku .= $sku . ',';
}
$tSku = substr($theSku, 0,-1);

echo '<script type="application/json+trustpilot">
   { 
      "recipientName": "'. $order->get_billing_first_name().'", 
      "recipientEmail": "'. $order->get_billing_email().'", 
      "referenceId": "'. $order->get_id().'", 
      "productSkus": ["'.$tSku.'"]
   }
</script>';
}
```

But the above is not working :( any help appreciated.

Comment: You should put this into the Thank You page, not sure you can enter scripts into an email

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains some minor errors

- `$order` is not an argument in the `woocommerce_email_header` hook
- `$email->id` is used in an if condition, to target the `customer_processing_order` email
- `$item->get_sku();` is replaced by `$product->get_sku();`

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_email_header( $email_heading, $email ) {    
    // Only for order processing email 
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {  
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = $email->object;
        
        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Empty string
            $theSku = '';
            
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
                $product = $item->get_product();
                
                // Get product SKU
                $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
                
                $theSku .= $product_sku . ',';
            }
            
            $tSku = substr( $theSku, 0, -1 );

            echo '<script type="application/json+trustpilot">
            { 
                "recipientName": "' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '",
                "recipientEmail": "' . $order->get_billing_email() . '", 
                "referenceId": "' . $order->get_id() . '", 
                "productSkus": ["' . $tSku . '"]
            }
            </script>';
        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'action_woocommerce_email_header', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Note:** the results can be found in the email source, one email client displays the results visually, the other does not, so it depends on which email client you use

Comment: Do you know how I can get order details within the template file (customer-processing-order.php) ? I think I figured it out but I need order details in this template

Comment: @AdrianV an email in WooCommerce never consists of 1 specific template file. 
Template files can be overwritten, however this is not recommended and therefore you can use hooks. Via hooks you can edit/add data in emails, but certain hooks appear more than once, in different template files. That's why you can target specific emails via an if condition (as applied in my answer), 
Whether you're going to modify a template file, or do it via hooks with an if condition, it comes down to the same thing.